# How to view top-level gradle file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I my Project tab I'm using the "Android" mode which conveniently groups all Gradle scripts together. I can only see the build.gradle files for the modules though, not the top-level build-gradle. Is there a way to list the top-level build.gradle here as well?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the one labeled `Project: [project name without the brackets]`:

[image]

If you can't see it, it most likely doesn't exist (or Android Studio doesn't see it). Make sure it exists, and if it does, invalidate caches and restart*. If it doesn't, create it.

<sub>* A lot of issues related to Android Studio can be fixed this way. If the gradle file exists, but Android Studio isn't seeing it, invalidate the caches and see if that fixes it</sub>

Comment: It does exist - I can see it when the tab is in "Project" mode and I have verified that the modules are actually using it. Invalidate caches and restart did not resolve the issue :/